# Oracle XE 21c and unixODBC error: Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: sql-server, oracle, unixodbc

I have Oracle Linux 8, Oracle XE 21c installed. Database work fine, listener, tnsnames etc configured. I'd like to have public database link to MS SQL server. I created link, made initMSSQL.ora file, /etc/odbc.ini is configured using  Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server driver, but all I get from ODBC log is [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified]

isql, osql work fine - I can log into MS SQL server without any issue. It seems problem is Oracle side. I did strace (I can see listener accesses odbc.ini file):

```
5587  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/odbc.ini", O_RDONLY) = 12
5587  fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=522, ...}) = 0
5587  read(12, "[SQLGIS]\n#Driver=/opt/microsoft/"..., 4096) = 522
```

but after several tries it fails:

```
19722 fstat(12, {st_dev=makedev(0x9, 0x7e), st_ino=269116215, st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_nlink=1, st_uid=54321, st_gid=54321, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=88, st_size=44167, st_atime=1678198928 /* 2023-03-07T16:22:08.082714912+0200 */, st_atime_nsec=82714912, st_mtime=1678199198 /* 2023-03-07T16:26:38.111993698+0200 */, st_mtime_nsec=111993698, st_ctime=1678199198 /* 2023-03-07T16:26:38.111993698+0200 */, st_ctime_nsec=111993698}) = 0
19722 write(12, "[ODBC][19722][1678199198.120056][SQLGetDiagRecW.c][596]\n\t\tExit:[SQL_NO_DATA]\n", 77) = 77
19722 close(12)                         = 0
19722 write(11, "hgopoer, line 240: got native error 0 and sqlstate IM002; message follows...\n", 77) = 77
19722 write(11, "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified {IM002}\n", 93) = 93
```

I've googled several day's without clue and tried every remedy I could find on "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified]" but no positive result.
Btw Same setup in Windows environment works very well.

Comment: So what's in your `/etc/odbc.ini` file? The snippet shown for the `[SQLGIS]` section suggests that the `Driver` line is commented out. But the presence of `[SQLGetDiagRecW.c][596]` in the trace suggests to me that it is at least connecting. On the SQL Server side does the Login's default database setting point to an existing database? On the client side does the `odbc.ini` file's `Database` setting point to an existing database?

Comment: "Accidentally" I created `[Default]` profile to `/etc/odbc.ini` file and this Oracle HS accepts! No more "server not found" error. New error is much more promising `[unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired {HYT00}` However it would not read rest of configuration parameters like `Server`, `Database`, `Port` etc. 
Any ideas about that?

Comment: So it seems Oracle understands only values defined in `[Default]` and Driver option in it. Other `[]` entries are ignored in `odbc.ini`. Any explanations about that? Seems to be a bit weird?

Comment: Got it working - in initXXX.ora file HS_LANGUAGE = AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1 any other gives driver load error. I'd like to have it UTF8 format, but let's investigate further (I need language specific characters like ü, õ, ä, ö letters etc)

Comment: To end this saga, I used `FreeTDS` driver what does proper encoding between Oracle and MSSQL Express so my "special characters" are correctly encoded. I did not investigate further why MS ODBC 18 driver does not do that.